# How to change the frame of a UIViewController in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiviewcontroller, admob

I am currently integrating a `UIViewController` with `UIViewControllerRepresentable` into my SwiftUI project and would now like to change the frame of the `UIViewController`.
For that I used this code:

```swift
let vc = UIViewController()
vc.view.frame.size = CGSize(width: kGADAdSizeBanner.size.width, height: kGADAdSizeBanner.size.height)
```

However, when I integrate the view created by UIViewControllerRepresentable into my SwiftUI project in a VStack with a list, the UIViewController does not have the size I want.
[Look at this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Drf6.png)

My hole code is:

```swift
func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
    let vc = UIViewController()
    vc.view.frame.size = CGSize(width: kGADAdSizeBanner.size.width, height: kGADAdSizeBanner.size.height)
    vc.view.backgroundColor = .gray
    vc.view.alpha = 0
    
    let bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)
    bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
    bannerView.alpha = 0
    bannerView.rootViewController = vc
    bannerView.delegate = context.coordinator
    bannerView.load(GADRequest())

    vc.view.addSubview(bannerView)
    
    return vc
}
```

`kGADSizeBanner` is a size variable from Google for the ad.

Also, I was wondering why my ad isn't appearing in the center of the gray UIViewController. Can someone help out?

What I tried so far:

1. `vc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`
2. `vc.view.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: kGADAdSizeBanner.size.width, height: kGADAdSizeBanner.size.height))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override [`sizeThatFits`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewcontrollerrepresentable/sizethatfits(_:uiviewcontroller:context:)-35p75) in your `UIViewControllerRepresentable` implementation.

For a fixed size, just return the `CGSize` you want, but you can also try experimenting with taking the `proposal` into account.

```
func sizeThatFits(_ proposal: ProposedViewSize, uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) -> CGSize? {
    kGADAdSizeBanner.size
}
```

The banner is not at the centre of the view controller, because it is at (0, 0), a typical default location for a view that you didn't set a position explicitly or added any constraints.

Comment: Thank you! It works! I am so happy .